# Connecting Windbg to Bochs virtual machine

Tags: windbg, terminate, bochs

I want to connect windbg to Bochs virtual machine in order to debug the os, But the windbg terminates when the os boot operation starts (without any error message.)

Please consider that I have already connected windbg to Bochs through com port.

Comment: Have you tried debugging WinDbg? It may terminate without an error message, but it won't terminate without an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this problem occurred was because of Windows first debug message. (the message was modified in Bochs for no reason and caused the windbg to crash)

I solved the problem by modifying the Bochs source code. I created a thread to create pipes after the os is booted so the Windows message is not being sent

Comment: This is not a very good answer. How exactly (file, class or line) did you change the source code of Bochs? Could you add those parts which you have modified to the answer? Since Bochs is open source, did you consider making that change part of the product?